# Operation in theano that always adds dimensions

Tags: python, theano

I'm looking for a way to write a function that takes two theano expressions `a` and `b` and does elementwise operation (let's say addition) on them so that `dimensions(a + b) = dimensions(a) + dimenisons(b)`.

In my case `a` will have one dimension and `b` will have two or three.

I was thinking about doing something like `a.dimshuffle('x', 'x', 0) + a.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x')` for 2 dimensional `b`, but I don't know how to get the number of dimensions of it. `b.shape` is a theano expression and doesn't support `len()`.

End goal of this is to calculate a distance from polyline at multiple points, this technique will be used multiple times, where `a` will have shape `(number_of_control_points,)` and `b` will be the 2D or 3D grid sampling points coordinates at which I'll be evaluating the distance.

Can I get the number of dimensions of an expression as a regular python value without evaluating the expression?

Alternative question: Is there a way to do the operation directly without explicit dimshuffle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `tile` with a bit broadcasting magic:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T

def general_outer(elem_op, a, b):
    a_shape = T.shape(a)
    b_shape = T.shape(b)
    return elem_op(T.tile(a, T.join(0,T.ones_like(a_shape),b_shape), b)) #note the broadcast
```